Spring Framework bean is Null
In my spring boot application, I've an
 @Autowired ConfigurableEnvironment env;
object in a @RestController class.
When I hit an endpoint that's calling
env.getPropertySources(); //Just for the sake of testing. not a real use case
the env object is not null.
Whereas I've an external dependency I've added to build.gradle.
That library has an @Configuration class that has an
@Autowired ConfigurableEnvironment object. This object is null when the library is trying to use it.
How can I force the bean from External library to be loaded in the last.
I've tried to create an ApplicationListener in my project, that destroys that bean and recreates it. This ApplicationListener has an @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE), to force this external bean to be recreated after all other beans are created.
But this is not working as well.

Did you write the library? Is it included in classpath scanning? What is instantiating the object?

what is the name of the library? Does the specific class from the library provide a setEnvironment() method?

An @Autowired field cannot be null. If an @Autowired field cannot be resolved the application wouldn't even start. So either you are doing something really weird, or accessing it too early (in the constructor for instance), or the class isn't created by Spring but rather yourself using new.
